# Web fonts and printed articles

Tags: fonts

Why is it advised not  to use web fonts for printed articles (using LaTeX)? What is the problem in using them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming here that by "web fonts", you mean "fonts developed by Microsoft for web use with low-resolution display devices (~72 dpi)". Fonts such as Verdana.

Verdana is a sans-serif font. The serifs would smudge the shapes at low-resolutions instead of guiding the eye on higher resolutions.

But we are heading towards high-resolution displays with, for example, Apple's Retina displays reaching laser printer comparable resolutions of >300 dpi.

So it would be better today to forget fonts like Verdana for body text.

Also you might be interested to read this:
http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2012/04/24/a-closer-look-at-font-rendering/